Diagonalisation in the proof of undecidability of the acceptance problem for Turing Machines
It's well-known that the language $A_{TM} = \{\langle M,w\rangle: \text{M is a turing machine that accepts w} \}$ is undecidable.
There's a standard proof that's presented in Sipser's "Introduction to the theory of Computation" (and in a number of other online sources I've checked). It's often claimed that the proof uses Cantor's diagonalisation method. I'm not sure I agree, and I was wondering if I've missed something.
The standard proof proceeds as follows. Assume there's a Turing Machine $T$ that decides $A_{TM}$. If $\langle M \rangle$ is an encoding of some turing machine $M$, we can make a second machine $D$ that rejects  $\langle M \rangle$ iff $M$ accepts $\langle M \rangle$ and vice versa. $D$ runs by applying $T$ to $\langle M, \langle M \rangle \rangle$ and negating the output. We then observe that $D$ accepts $\langle M \rangle$ iff $M$ rejects  $\langle M \rangle$, and in particular $D$ accepts $\langle D \rangle$ iff $D$ rejects  $\langle D \rangle$, a contradiction.
It seems to me that this self-referential argument avoids the need to use diagonalisation. The diagonalisation argument should be something like this:
Let $\{M_1, M_2, ...\}$ be a enumeration of the set of Turing machines. Let $\{w_1, w_2, ... \}$ be an enumeration of all inputs. As above, let $T$ decide $A_{TM}$ and use $T$ to construct a machine $D$ that accepts $w_i$ iff $M_i$ rejects $w_i$. By construction, $D$ is not in our list since it disagrees with all other machines on at least one input. This contradicts the assertion that we had enumerated all Turing machines. Therefore $D$ cannot exist.
Note that we can use any sequence of words here: $w_i$ does not need to be a description of $M_i$, unlike in the self-referential proof. So it seems like we can prove non-existence of $D$ either using self-reference (first proof) or by showing it doesn't live in our enumeration of Turing machines (second proof, diagonalization). Is this correct, or have I made a mistake somewhere?

We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See here and here. Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Self-reference and diagonalisation are very closely related. The diagonalisation in your first argument appears when you apply $M$ to $\langle M \rangle$; in the most general sense, diagonalisation is the morphism $X \to X \times X$ given by duplicating the variable: $\lambda x. (x, x)$.
Lawvere's fixed point theorem offers a unifying perspective on these things: see A Universal Approach to Self-Referential Paradoxes, Incompleteness and Fixed Points.

The paper you linked to looks fascinating. Looks like it makes a real effort to strip out the category theory in order to lower the bar for non-specialists like myself. Thanks for the reference!

You are essentially right that the first proof does not directly use diagonalization, though since it uses a self-referential argument (calling $M$ on input $\langle M \rangle$) it can be thought of as equivalent to diagonalization.
Naïm Favier offers an abstract view of why this is the case; let me be a bit more concrete.
Similar to your second proof, let's make an infinite table where the rows are $M_1, M_2, M_3, \ldots$ and the columns are $\langle M_1 \rangle, \langle M_2 \rangle, \langle M_3 \rangle, \ldots$. Now enter a $1$ in the cell at row $i$, column $j$ if $M_i$ accepts $\langle M_j \rangle$ and a $0$ otherwise. For example:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
& \langle M_1 \rangle & \langle M_2 \rangle & \langle M_3 \rangle & \cdots \cr
M_1 & 1 &&& \cdots \cr
M_2 && 0 && \cdots \cr
M_3 &&& 1 & \cdots \cr
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}
$$
If $T$ recognizes $A_{TM}$, then $T$ must accept $\langle M_i, \langle M_j \rangle \rangle$ iff there is a $1$ in row $i$ column $j$.
Then we can construct the sequence that differs along the diagonal: the $i$th value is $0$ if $(i, i)$ is $1$ and $1$ otherwise (this is exactly the machine $D$ in your first proof); e.g., $0, 1, 0, \ldots$ in our example above.
Due to the fact $T$ is decidable, this sequence is also decidable.
But by the diagonal argument this sequence does not appear in any row, which is a contradiction.

Thanks for the write-up Caleb! The issue I have with this explanation is that when we use diagonalisation, we're not using the descriptions $<M_i>$ in an essential way: they could be any distinct inputs and the proof would work just as well.

@SimonLyons Sure, that's true -- my point is that the Turing machine $D$ is exactly the sequence construction along the diagonal.
